# Using conditional statements in r data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use data.table to recode a variable based on certain conditions. My original dataset has around 30M records and after all variable creation around 130 variables. I used the methods suggested here: [conditional statements in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018564/conditional-statements-in-data-table) **(M1)** and also here [data.table: Proper way to do create a conditional variable when column names are not known?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450696/data-table-proper-way-to-do-create-a-conditional-variable-when-column-names-are) **(M2)**

My goal is get the equivalent of the below code but something that is applicable using data.table

```
samp$lf5 <- samp$loadfactor5

samp$lf5 <- with(samp, ifelse(loadfactor5 < 0, 0, lf5))
```

I will admit that I don't understand .SD and .SDCols very well, so I might be using it wrong. The code and errors from **(M1)** and **(M2)** are given below and the **sample dataset is here: http://goo.gl/Jp97Wn**

**(M1)**

```
samp[,lf5 = if(loadfactor5 <0) 0 else loadfactor5]
```

Error Message

```
Error in `[.data.table`(samp, , lf5 = if (loadfactor5 < 0) 0 else loadfactor5) : 
unused argument (lf5 = if (loadfactor5 < 0) 0 else loadfactor5)
```

When I do this:

```
samp[,list(lf5 = if(loadfactor5 <0) 0 else loadfactor5)]
```

it gives lf5 as a list but not as part of the samp data.table and does not really apply the condition as lf5 still has values less than 0.

**(M2)**

```
Col1 <- "loadfactor5"
Col2 <- "lf5"

setkeyv(samp,Col1)
samp[,(Col2) :=.SD,.SDCols = Col1][Col1<0,(Col2) := .SD, .SDcols = 0]
```

I get the following error

```
Error in `[.data.table`(samp, , `:=`((Col2), .SD), .SDCols = Col1) : 
unused argument (.SDCols = Col1)
```

Any insights on how to finish this appreciated. My dataset has 30M records so I am hoping to use data.table to really cut the run time down.

Thanks,

Krishnan

Comment: `samp[, lf5 := ifelse(loadfactor5 < 0, 0, loadfactor5)]`; search for `.SD` on SO to find out what it is/does

Comment: I was able to use this command to get the desired result.

Comment: @Krishnan, could you please answer it yourself and accept it so that the Q remains answered? Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Answer provided by [eddi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817778/eddi) and included here for the sake of completeness.

`samp[, lf5 := ifelse(loadfactor5 < 0, 0, loadfactor5)]`

Comment: I guess the quid of the question is to use ":=" instead of  "=".  And you could also write  samp[, lf5 := loadfactor5*(loadfactor>=0)]

Comment: you should use `fifelse` which is faster and implemented in data.table >= 1.12.4

Answer (score 9):

Another way (which I prefer because it's, in my opinion, cleaner):

```
samp[, lf5 := 0]; samp[loadfactor5 > 0, lf5 := loadfactor5];
```

I use data.table with a dataset with 90M rows; I am continually amazed at how fast data.table is for operations like the above.